# InvalidOperationException with foreach even though the collection is locked

Tags: c#, multithreading, collections

Lately, I've been trying to make an old project of mine work using multiple threads, and obviously collections are part of the fun. The problem is that one bit of code keeps crashing randomly (not often but still noticeably enough):

[image]

`Monde` is a SynchronizedCollection, and I'm locking it to prevent simultaneous writes, but it's still complaining about it. Is there something I'm missing about it?

**edit:** I am aware that the SynchronizedCollection class only locks automatically during the creation of the Enumeration, hence a plain foreach isn't enough and that's why I'm enclosing the whole loop in a `lock` block. The problem is in the fact that the collection somehow gets modified while the thread is inside the `lock` block, which shouldn't happen.

Also, none of the classes under the .NET 4 concurrent API fulfill all my needs so I don't really have a choice if I don't want to make the whole codebase more complicated than it already is.

Comment: I'm perfectly aware of that (see my comment on Siavash's answer), that's why I'm enclosing the whole loop in the `lock` block. It should effectively lock the collection but it doesn't, that's where the problem resides

Comment: What does `Physique` do?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. Locking on the `SyncRoot` successfully prevents any concurrent mutation of the `SynchronizedCollection` (assembly `System.ServiceModel`) in my experiments.

Comment: Can you share a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you're using `SynchronizedCollection` then you won't need to wrap it in `lock` because it does the operations with lock under the hood. And second `SynchronizedCollection` is from .Net 2.0 era, and if you're porting your legacy code then you'd better use collections from `System.Collections.Concurrent` namespace instead. They are newer, more optimized and don't rely on locking and blocking strategies.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Wrong, the SynchronizedCollection only locks during the creation of the enumerator but not during the enumeration itself (which makes sense, the CLR enumerator model doesn't allow such things). My problem is that even with a lock, the collection gets modified which violates the concurrency contract

Comment: @zdimension can you test if using `SynchronizedReadOnlyCollection` instead of `SynchronizedCollection` will fix the problem?

Comment: and the bigger is question is what are you doing in Physique method? does it modify the collection by any chance?